# TSQL Convert VARCHAR of HH:MM:SS.mmm to TIME

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Unable to convert `15600.02` value to time .

Ex :

```
select cast(stuff(stuff('15600.02',5,0,':'),3,0,':') as time)
```

ERROR :

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

can any one help on it .

Thanks,
Kumar

Comment: And what time do you think that should render? And are you sure those aren't seconds after midnight?

Comment: `'15600.02'` *isn't* a time, and it's certainly not in the format `HH:MM:SS.mmm` (which is hours, Months, seconds, and minutes? I assume you actually mean `hh:mm:ss.nnn`) What ar eyou actually expecting here?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is really what this number represents...

The location you are using in the STUFF command is 1 off when earlier than 10 o'clock.

This isn't pretty, but try `select cast(stuff(stuff(REPLACE(SPACE(7 - CHARINDEX('.', '15600.02' + '.')),' ','0') + '15600.02',5,0,':'),3,0,':') as time)`